# Spinner does not get focus

Tags: android, focus, spinner

I'm using 4 `EditText` fields and 2 spinners in an activity. The order of these components are 2 `EditText`, then 2 spinners and then 2 `EditText` fields.

The problem occurs when I transfer focus (with the help of soft keyboard next button) from `EditText` to spinner, spinner does not get the focus and the focus is transferred to the next `EditText` field that was placed after the spinners.

I have used requestfocus() on spinner, but it did not work.

How do I make sure the spinner gets focus?

Comment: Please grant the answer flag.

Comment: Minus 1 for not granting the selected answer.

Answer (score 44):

I managed to find a solution other then repositioning my Spinner. In the EditText **before** the spinner, add this listener:

```
editTextBefore.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            hideKeyboard();
            textView.clearFocus();
            spinner.requestFocus();
            spinner.performClick();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

You also need to add these line to able spinner to get focus:

```
spinner.setFocusable(true); // can be done in XML preferrable
```

My hideKeyboard function was just a visual detail that I wanted to add so the keyboard get hidden:

```
private void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

Hope I have helped in this tricky question.
The flag `InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS` can be [found in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html).

Comment: You don't have to set focusableInTouchMode?

Comment: It would be helpful to set focusableInTouchMode. Also, it seemed not to work if you try this in XML, try programmatically.

Comment: In addition you have to set the attribute `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` for `EditText` in xml.

Answer (score 20):

Thanks, I have solved by doing the following:

1. I set the Spinner object on top (within the `onCreate` method) just to make sure that my code gets executed first
2. I used the following:

   ```
   Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
   s1.setFocusable(true); 
   s1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
   s1.requestFocus();
   ```

Comment: You clearly got the solution from @shanet so you should have just selected their answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is a shot in the dark, but try setting the focusable property (in XML or in code; whatever way you are doing it) to true on the spinner.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:focusable

EDIT: Also, see this question: [Can't manage to requestFocus a Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917921/cant-manage-to-requestfocus-a-spinner)

Comment: thanx i have solved by doing the following:  1) I set the Spinner object on top (Within the onCreate method) just to make sure that my code gets executed first. 2) I used the following:

Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); s1.setFocusable(true); s1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

Comment: @Shameen  You could've set those flags in XML.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem. I solved it using the nextFocusDown/Up/Left/Right properties.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tPhone"
    ...
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/sCountry"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sCountry"
    ....
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:nextFocusUp = "@+id/tPhone"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/tStreet"/>

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/tStreet"
    ...
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:nextFocusUp = "@+id/sCountry"/>
```

But why this is even neccessary... beats me.