# Android: EditText NextFocusDown not trigger Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-spinner

In my application I have one registration screen, There are lot of EditTexts and Spinners.
I want to go through the Registrations field one by one.

So I applied `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` . But It ignores all the Spinners. It will give focus only to EditText.  I have also tried `setNextFocusDownId()`. This is also ignore the spinners.

```
   <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/reportentry11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numbers"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="phone" 
            >
           <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/reportentry12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_exp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                android:text="EXP:"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spin_date"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/spin_year"
                android:text="date"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spin_year"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                  android:nextFocusDown="@+id/cvc"
                android:text="year"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cvc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:hint="@string/reg_label_cvc"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/reg_label_fname"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/reg_label_address"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/reg_label_city"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/pr_spin" />

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/reportentry13"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_pr"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="PROV:"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/pr_spin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="date"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pcode"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:hint="@string/reg_label_pcode"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register_register_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/green_button_bg"
            android:onClick="completeClicked"
            android:text="@string/reg_label_complete"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Please provide me the best way to trigger the spinners.

Comment: I think this link will help you.... [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443212/spinner-did-not-got-focus



Thanks...

Answer (score 7):

On your edit texts, override onEditorAction and give focus (or do whatever like open your spinner)...

```
yourEditTXT.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionID, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionID == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                //do your stuff here...
                return true;
            }
            return false; 
    }
});
```

Edit 12/4:
I see you were still struggling with this as of last night, if you didn't find a solution (and didn't post one) or to help others who may read this, this may help to get from spinner to edit text.

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());            

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentview, View v, int position, long id) {
            // your spinner proces code 
            // then when you are done, 
            yourEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);  //if this is not already set
            yourEditText.requestFocus();  //to move the cursor
            final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);  // this line and the one above will open the soft keyboard if it doesn't already open
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
    };
```

Comment: Its working but, popup spinner list is not showing, only spinner is highlight

Comment: what @GMRamesh said plus yourWidget.performClick() should do the trick.

Comment: your code for going edittext to spinner is working , provide me code for spinner to edittext

Comment: @sridhar, i have edited the answer, check and let me know.... you have to add next edittextid over there

Answer (score 2):

do the following in your xml file:

```
<Spinnner
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  android:nextFocusDown="@+id/youedittextid"
 />
```

Comment: it was working for me... check with your code thoroughly and change accordingly... its not like that if you copy paste the above answer it should work... you have to make changes accordingly to you

Comment: @sridhar,...in your code you have two spinners in a LinearLayout so in that you are trying to go to the edittext  which is not in the same Linear Layout... I suggest you to use only one Relative layout and check whether it works or not..

Comment: Is your Spinner  android:nextFocusDown="@+id/spin_year" -->    android:id="@+id/spin_year" is working in the same LinearLayout.... If that works than for EditText also it should work for 100%

Comment: @Sridhar and GM I see you didn't post any updates, so I edited my post below, hope you find it to be useful if you didn't find a solution.  Also please update this question with the solution if you found one other than that last night.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solutions above to focus on Spinners, here are further troubles with ime options:

If the `spinners` are between the `EditTexts`, then the `EditTexts` that are below the `spinners` ignore `imeOption="actionDone"` and `lines="1"` attributes. In both the cases they accept enter keys and move to next line, when, it should not allow the enter key event.

I found that though the listener for ime was still intact, the ime option set to whatever (next or done), it changed to 0.

So my answer is for second part while I am still trying to make spinners focusable:

xml:

```
     <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_40"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_8"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_8"
                android:gravity="start|bottom"
                android:hint="@string/et_1"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textCapWords" />
<!--This ime option works fine-->
<!--lots of spinners in between these Edit texts-->

                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_2"
                android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_8"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_8"
                android:gravity="start|bottom"
                android:hint="@string/et_2"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
<!--this actionDone is ignored and set to 0-->
```

[value of actionNext = 5 while that of actionDone = 0, but for edit text et2 reports as 0 in the listener]
set listener:

```
...
        EditText et_1 = view.findViewById(R.id.et_1);
        fet_1.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
        //==
        EditText et_2 = view.findViewById(R.id.et_2);
        et_2.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
...
```

The handling of listeners where the ime actions are ignored too:

```
@Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionID, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        FontEditText et_1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.et_1);
        //==
        EditText et_2 = getView().findViewById(R.id.et_2);
        final int id = textView.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.et_1: {
                if (actionID == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                    // works actionID = 5.
//inherited method
                    activity.hideKeyboard(textView);
                    fet_bus_entity.clearFocus();
                    et_business_add.requestFocus();
                    et_business_add.performClick();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
            case R.id.et_2: {
//following line doesn't work hence commented, value of actionID = 0 here.
//                if (actionID == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                    et_business_add.clearFocus();
//inherited method
                    activity.hideKeyboard(textView);
                    return true;
//                }

            }
//            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```