# Clear focus neither requestFocus( ) work with EditText

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, spinner

I need to clear focus from an Edit Text and put it on another element, the problem is that the focus always is on the Edit Text, no matter what I do, It never loses the focus.

I want to change the focus when the next button of the Soft Keyboard is clicked, so I use an Editor Option Listener for do it, that works fine, because the keyboard is hidden.

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
    InputMethodManager imm = 
    (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(tviewNombreNC.getWindowToken(), 0);
    tviewNombreNC.clearFocus();
    spinnerNuevaConf.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I've tried with requestFocus(), with clearFocus and with both at same time, but nothing is done. If the Edit Text is never focused, the others elements can get the focus, but when the ET gets it, the others elements don't achieve catch it.

**Layout**

```
<TextView android:text="@string/nuevaconfiguracion_titulo"
android:textSize="25sp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
android:textStyle="bold"/>

<ImageView  android:src="@drawable/barra_verde"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="5dp" android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/barra_verde" 
    android:layout_width="4dp" android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"       
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/view_nuevaconfiguracion_1_nombre_focus"/>

    <TextView android:text="@string/nuevaconfiguracion_1_nombre" 
    android:textSize="18sp" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_width="72dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="40dp" 
    android:id="@+id/view_nuevaconfiguracion_usuario"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal" 
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="18sp"
    android:singleLine="true" android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/view_nuevaconfiguracion_moneda"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/barra_verde" android:layout_width="4dp" 
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/view_nuevaconfiguracion_1_divisa_focus"/>

    <TextView android:textSize="18sp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
    android:text="@string/nuevaconfiguracion_1_divisa" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_width="72dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <Spinner android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="40dp" 
    android:id="@+id/view_nuevaconfiguracion_moneda"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal" 
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you want to manually set the focus to another view? Clicking on the next button of the soft keyboard should set the focus to the next element by itself.

Comment: Yes, It's supposed it has to do it, but doesn't.

Comment: Could you add the layout file?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443212/spinner-did-not-got-focus), you need to add `spinnerNuevaConf.performClick();` after `spinnerNuevaConf.requestFocus();` and make the spinner focusable. I tried this and it generally works, but it doesn't look nice, as the spinner is placed somewhere in the middle of the screen, because the keyboard doesn't get hidden immediately... I don't know if there is a solution for this.

Comment: It works, but the problem is that the EditText recovers the focus immediately, thanks anyway