# How to get the TextView in the ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have create a `ListView` and it has `TextView` in this `ListView`.

The id `TextView` is `value_text`. I use `viewHolder.value_text` to get the `TextView` like the following code.

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final ViewHolder viewHolder;
            Log.d(TAG, "getView");
            if(view == null){
                view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.streamid_data, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.value_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Value_text);
                viewHolder.value_text.setText("1");

            }else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            return view;
        }
```

And I want to use `thread` and change the `text` for `viewHolder.value_text`. But it seems can not get the `value_text` in the `thread`.
The `runnable` is outside of the `getView method`.

```
final Runnable setList = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //change the text of value_text
        }
    };
```

How do I get the `TextView` at outside of the `getView method`; ?

Comment: Your runnable might be outside of the `getView` method right ?

Comment: @Martin Implement `onItemClick` method for `ListView` or get data for your arraylist.

Comment: 1. you can declare your `TextView` variable as publuc;  2. You can set your TextView with `View`, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956742/updating-textview-without-losing-spinner-focus-in-busy-listview

Answer (score 0):

Make the ViewHolder variable global. then you can access textview in Thread.

```
     // Global in Adapter Class
     ViewHolder accessable_ViewHolder;


    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d(TAG, "getView");
        if(view == null){
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.streamid_data, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.value_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Value_text);
            viewHolder.value_text.setText("1");

        }else {
            accessable_ViewHolder= (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        return view;
    }



 // Thread

 final Runnable setList = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //change the text of value_text

        accessable_ViewHolder.value_text.setText("Value set from Thread");
    }
 };
```

Comment: Yes you can access the textview. But this code makes no sense as the right textview will have disappeared with the the next getView() where `accessable_ViewHolder` will be assigned a different instance.