# request focus not working for material spinner android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, focus, android-spinner

I use a [Material Spinner](https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner) in a fragment and I want to request focus for it programmatically. The weird thing is, that it already worked several days ago. I checked my old version, where it is also not working any more. So maybe it is some Android update issue. The library was not changed in the meantime.

For requesting the focus i use these lines of code

```
inputHardness.setFocusable(true);
inputHardness.setFocusableInTouchMode( true );
inputHardness.requestFocus();
```

Please help me, I am quite stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917921/cant-manage-to-requestfocus-a-spinner

Comment: Nope. I know this question, but the answer didn´t help me.

Comment: Try asking the question here too: https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner/issues