# Set state for Android button

Tags: android, button, state

I declare a Android button like this:

```
<Button
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/festival_button_selector"
 android:textColor="@color/white"
 android:text="@string/STR_FEST_SELOFF"
 android:onClick="onBtnFestSelectionClick"
/>
```

And here is the content of this button's selector background (festival_button_selector):

```
<item android:state_focused="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/festival_button_focus"
    />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/festival_button_press"
    />
<item android:state_focused="false" 
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/festival_button"
    />
```

Actually, I want to set this button background is in "focus" state (so button background will be festival_button_focus) as default. If we click other button, this button background will return to "normal" state (with background is festival_button). Can we do it?

P/S: I don't want to change festival_button_selector. It'll be ideal if we have a function like button.setFocusState(true) to make this button on focus state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take as look at [requestFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29) to set the initial focus state.

Comment: requestFocus() looks right, but unfortunately this method is buggy in Android 2.1 and 2.2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211851/requestfocus-problem. Anyway, thanks for response.

Comment: from looking at your link it looks like the solution is to use a runnable to set the focus.

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFestivalSelection)).requestFocus();
            }
        }); //-> it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to call [View.requestFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29) on your Button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item android:state_focused="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/festival_button_focus"
    />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/festival_button_press"
    />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/festival_button"
    />
```

try this