# requestFocus doesn't work properly for EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, focus, text-cursor

A lot of time was spent to solve the problem, and it looks easy, but I'm really tired and couldn't  find the solution.
I have an Activity, activity has 4 EditText components, 2 of them has popup menu (AlertDialog) which contain the list, next one - is disabled for edit, and last one - is editable, and should show the soft keyboard, when user is tapping on it.

Also, my root LinearLayout has LinearLayout which contain inside RelativeLayout. The last one is need for AdvBanner. Last LinearLayout(RelativeLayout) is aligned to the bottom of root layout.

The part of XML that describes it:

```
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
      android:gravity="bottom">
  <RelativeLayout 
      android:id="@+id/AdvLayoutReserveArea" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="50dp" 
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
      android:gravity="bottom" /> 
  </LinearLayout>
```

When activity is start, editable EditText has focus with **GREEN** border and cursor is blinking. After few seconds left, the AdvBanner is loaded and shown. When it happens, editable EditText lost  focus.. from this moment, my life be like a nightmare.

Let's look step by step.

**Problem 1.** 
If in **THIS MOMENT** (when Adv loaded and appears) user is editing an EditText field via the soft keyboard, focus is lost, border take a **GRAY** color, and if user continue to typing  a text is have no result - symbols are not printed (CURSOR in EditText is too lost).

I THINK any user will be annoyed  - when you typing text, and cursor is inactive, because in background some adv is loaded and it take focus for self.

To solve this, in method when Adv is loaded (is shown) I try to back focus manually to EditText by requestFocus method.

```
public void onAdLoaded() 
    {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// add app specific code for this event here...
// called when an ad is successfully displayed on device            
    CountEdit1.requestFocus();
}
```

Yes, the cursor is returned to EditText field, and if soft keyboard is active, user can still typing text, but border of EditText field stay GRAY...

**NOTE:** actually I'm not sure about the difference between GREEN and GRAY border of focused EditText.. GREEN is usually when user is tapping on it, and GRAY, probably, when we want to request a focus manually (using requestFocus() etc)

**Problem 2.** (As result of solvation Problem #1).
After soft keyboard was closed, if user tap on editable EditText field, it take focus and cursor appears inside, but no reaction for showing soft keyboard again! Tapping of it do not show soft keyboard, but looks like the edit field in copy mode - when user can select a text and cut/copy it to clipboard.

My goal is easy for a first look. I just want to SAVE the cursor and focus to editable EditText field (CountEdit1) while soft keyboard is shown and user typing some text.
And normal reaction when user tapping EditText - as usually, just show me the soft keyboard!

I read all issues here, I combined different methods (clearFocus, requestFocusFromTouch etc), just not enough of time and space to describe all that I tried to do to solve this. The main problems are described above.

Hope for help and solving the problem...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The goal is solved, the workaround is an easier than I thought. Problem #2 is fixed by using onClick () method. Sufficient condition for appearing of soft keyboard that use of both clearFocus() and requestFocus() methods.

> ```
>    CountEdit1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>
>       @Override
>       public void onClick(View v)
>       {
>               CountEdit1.clearFocus();
>         CountEdit1.requestFocus();
>       }
>     });
> ```

The soft keyboard appears when user is tapping on the EditText field.
Fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Works for me:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
editField.requestFocus();
mgr.showSoftInput(editField, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
userInput.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                userIdInput.requestFocus();

            }
        });
```

Have a go at this and tell if your problem is still unsolved.

Comment: Thanks, but this code not solve the problem. I also earlier played with the same code. I put it in my activity class, but still have no progress. In additionally to main description I have 2 ways with half-solving: 1) if I remove CountEdit1.requestFocus(); from public void onAdLoaded(), then Soft Keyboard is appears if user tap on EditText even after Adv is loaded, BUT.. if Adv loaded while softkeyboard was shown, the user lost a cursor in EditText field and unable to continue of inputting text..

Comment: 2) with CountEdit1.requestFocus(); in onAdLoaded(), user is able to continue edit field after Adv is loaded, but after softkeyboard is closed, next tapping by the EditText do not show soft keyboard again! This situation is tired me so much..

Comment: Are you also not being to display the soft keyboard manually if it's not coming up on its own..?

Comment: Yes, even if I try manually to call a soft keyboard it not appears.. I tried to use showSoftKeyboard method    private void showSoftKeyboard(View v)
    { InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(CountEdit1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    }
inside CountEdit1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() and CountEdit1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() but it not helps me again.. even here, when user tapping an EditText, (descrided Problem #2) - soft keyboard not appears.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It Works for me. Surprised that there aren't any more upvotes.

Comment: @RahimRahimov agreed, this should be the correct answer. All this kind of visual UI updates needs to be on the main thread and with a "post" you're sure of that.

Answer (score 1):

You should request focus after view is created in fragment or activity:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CountEdit1.requestFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public void onAdLoaded() 
    {  
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
             handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     CountEdit1.requestFocus();
                     InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) base.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                     mgr.showSoftInput(CountEdit1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                     CountEdit1.setSelection(CountEdit1.getText().length());
                 }
             },0);
}
```